# What does the kernel compile rule exact mean?

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-kernel, gnu-make, kernel-module

What does the kernel compile rule `-C xxx M=xxx` exactly mean?

I have seen the compile rule as follows many times:

```
$(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
$(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) src=$(PWD) modules
```

while the `KDIR` equals for example

```
/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
```

or

```
/usr/src/kernel-headers
```

I want to know the meaning of the `KDIR`. Linux headers or the Linux kernel source code?
Someone uses `SUBDIRS` argument, but others use `M` and `src` argument. Is there any difference?

Answer (score 1):

**-C *dir*** is the **make** command-line option to change directory before reading makefiles. All kernel make operations start in the *kernel build* directory (which may or may not be the same directory as the *kernel source* directory).

Makefiles for external (out-of-tree) kernel modules have rules that run a sub-make in the kernel build directory:

```
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) _other parameters_
```

Here, `$(KDIR)` is a Makefile variable that should be set to the path of the *kernel build* directory. (The name `KDIR` is not important, but it is a convenient name that is otherwise unused by the kernel Makefiles themselves.)

For example, the Makefile for the external module could set `KDIR` as follows:

```
KDIR ?= "/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build"
```

That sets `KDIR` to the *kernel build* directory for the currently running kernel unless `KDIR` has already been set to something else. For example, it could be set externally in an environment variable, or set on the `make` command line:

```
$ make KDIR=/path/to/some/kernel/build   # sets KDIR to a specified kernel build directory
```

or:

```
$ make  # lets KDIR be set to the default in the Makefile
```

Between kernel versions 2.6.6 and 5.3.x, these two basically did the same thing:

```
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
```

`$(PWD)` is an environment variable set by the shell that expands to the process's current working directory. For building an external kernel module, this should be the directory containing the external module's sources and its Makefile.

These `SUBDIRS=$(PWD)` or `M=$(PWD)` options are telling the kernel sub-make's Makefile to run a sub-make in the specified directory (the directory containing the external module's Makefile and sources).

It is probably better to use `$(CURDIR)` instead of `$(PWD)` there, since `CURDIR` is set to the current working directory by 'make' itself.

The `M=` form was introduced in kernel version 2.6.6.  Prior to kernel version 2.6.6, the `SUBDIRS=` form had to be used instead. The `SUBDIRS=` form was deprecated for kernel versions 5.0 to 5.3.x, and is no longer supported for kernel version 5.4 onwards.

An alternative to specifying `M=` on the command line is to set and export the `KBUILD_EXTMOD` environment variable:

```
KDIR ?= "/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build"

KBUILD_EXTMOD := $(PWD)
export KBUILD_EXTMOD

all:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) modules
```

These all result in `KBUILD_EXTMOD` being set somehow in the Makefile for the kernel sub-make. It will use `KBUILD_EXTMOD` from the environment, if set, otherwise it will use the `M=` or `SUBDIRS=` setting from the command line to set `KBUILD_EXTMOD`.

One of your examples showed the following form:

```
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) src=$(PWD) modules
```

I don't know why the `src=$(PWD)` parameter is used there.

Answer (score 0):

From this link : https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kbuild/makefiles.html

`$(src)` is a relative path which points to the directory where the *Makefile* is located. Always use `$(src)` when referring to files located in the src tree.

And from my experiences as a kernel compiler :

`M` stands for "Modules" , individual modules that you may want to add in to the kernel. You can also compile these modules individually and add in to the kernel.